# GPO not applying: Access Denied (Security Filtering)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

Windows Server 2012 R2 Domain with users logging into a Windows Server 2008 R2 terminal server:

I've got a simple User GPP which implements a registry edit on the Windows 2008 machine.  The registry edit has **Item Level Targeting** enabled which targets the Windows Server 2008 computer specifically, using its DNS name (`computer.domain.com`).

In security filtering it is restricted to only a single user group `some.users`.  I've checked the `Delegation` tab and `some.users` has both `Read` access and `Apply Group Policy`.  I have also added `Domain Computer` with `Read` access to the permissions list.

When I run `gpresult /user:specific.user /h gpresult.html` I am receiving an `Access denied (Security Filtering)` error.  Inexplicably, when I also check the applied group membership in `gpresult.html`, it is showing `domain\some.users`.

I'm really stuck here, as `gpresult` shows `specific.user` as belonging to `some.users` group, and `some.users` has `Read` and `Apply` access in `Security Filtering`, so why is it getting denied?

I even tried creating a brand new `test.user` and `test.group` and changing the `Security Filtering` to apply ONLY to `test.group`, *and the policy applied successfully* when I logged in as `test.user`!  But when I change it back to `some.users`, it starts getting denied again if I log in as `specific.user`.  :(

Comment: Try it without item-level targeting. I suspect that may have something to do with it.

Comment: ok, but it would show me `Access Denied (Security Filtering)` if it was failing the Item-Level Targeting check?

also, why would it have worked - the very same GPO just with a different security filter - when I changed it to `test.group`?